# How to add data to PowerShell report if system offline

Tags: powershell

I Have the following script, it works great. However if a system is offline, how can I add system offline to the exported csv?

```
get-wmiobject -ComputerName $Server -query `
    "SELECT * FROM CCM_Application" -namespace "ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK" | `
  Where-Object {$_.InstallState -eq 'NotInstalled'} | `
  Select @{Label='ComputerName';Expression={$Server}},Name,Id,SoftwareVersion | `
  Export-CSV dest:\Scans\HQ_Apps_Missing_20210611.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a try/catch statement:

```
Try { 
    $info = get-wmiobject -ComputerName $Server -query `
    "SELECT * FROM CCM_Application" -namespace "ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK" | `
    Where-Object {$_.InstallState -eq 'NotInstalled'} | `
    Select @{Label='ComputerName';Expression={$Server}},Name,Id,SoftwareVersion
}
Catch {
    $info = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        ComputerName=$Server
        Name="System Offline"
        Id="System Offline"
        SoftwareVersion="System Offline"
        }
}
$info | Export-CSV dest:\Scans\HQ_Apps_Missing_20210611.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

You may need to edit some to meet your needs.

Comment: I tried this, however it did not output to the directory. Any Idea?